# DOH command-line testing of JavaScript functions outside of the Dojo root

Tags: javascript, testing, command-line, dojo, doh

I'm trying to run DOH from dojo-1.3.2 to test simple Javascript functions from command-line. However, I can't seem to get anything to run and the net seems to be devoid of DOH command-line documentation.

Ideally the structure I would like is:

Tests reside:
C:\myproject\tests\

Dojo reside:
C:\dojo-1.3.2\util\doh

As of right now I've put a simple test in ..\doh\tests

I try running while in the ..\doh directory:

**java -jar ..\shrinksafe\js.jar runner.js testModule=tests.module**

Each time I get:

*js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "window" is not defin
ed.
An exception occurred: Error: Could not load 'tests.module';
 last tried 'tests/module.js'
0 tests to run in 0 groups*

Is there something I should be doing that I have left out? I've also tried pointing to the dojo.js file using dojoUrl= but still the same error.

As far as I can see my tests do not use window anywhere. I have three files:

**tests/module.js**

```
dojo.provide("tests.module");
dojo.require("tests.functions.functions");
```

**tests/functions/functions.js**

```
dojo.provide("tests.functions.functions");
dojo.require("tests.demoFunctions");

doh.register("tests.functions.functions", [
    function test_alwaysTrue(){
        doh.assertTrue(tests.demoFunctions.alwaysTrue());
    }
]);
```

**tests/demoFunctions.js**

```
    dojo.provide("tests.demoFunctions");

tests.demoFunctions.alwaysTrue = function(){
    return true;
};
```

I've also tried restructuring the directory to have ../dojo-1.3.2/ contain the tests. Running the same command as above from command-prompt fails identically.
Dir Structure:

```
/dojo-1.3.2

   /dojo
   /tests
   ...
   /util

      /shrinksafe
      ...
      /doh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where the 'window' is coming from, but I don't think doh ever worked properly with tests outside the Dojo directory. Does it work if you copy util/doh to be a peer of your tests directory?

Comment: I've moved my /tests/... directory into util/doh/ and have run the same command "java -jar ..\shrinksafe\js.jar runner.js testModule=tests.module" and I still have the same issue. I've also tried an updated version of js.jar and the dojo-1.4.0 runner.js. Nothing had gotten better.

Comment: Sorry, I have moved the /tests folder to be a peer (not child this time) of util/doh/ and it still fails

Comment: ok, one more thing... try renaming your 'tests' directory and all the tests.* references to something else...  I don't know where it is, but I think tests.* maps to dojo.*  When you run the runner.js with its default dojo tests, it references them all as tests.*  Dijit and DojoX tests don't do this.  Sounds like something which needs to be cleaned up!

Comment: I've renamed everything and still nothing. I have noticed that removing the 'testModule=....' parameters does cause DOH to look in the dojo.* dir though. As well, adding the parameter testUrl=..., the error output changes slightly to:

...\util\doh>java -jar ..\shrinksafe\js.jar runner.js testUrl=tests\module.js testModule=tests.module

js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined.

js: "..\..\dojo\dojo.js", line 16: exception from uncaught JavaScript throw: Error: Could not load 'tests.functions.functions'; last tried '../tests/functions/f
unctions.js'

Comment: I took the files you listed above, put them in a peer directory called 'tests' and it failed.  I renamed the directory to 'foo' along with all the tests.* -> foo.* and it worked.

Comment: What was the exact command you used? "java -jar ..\shrinksafe\js.jar runner.js testModule=foo.module" ?

Are you using dojo-1.3.2's version of DOH? I've moved and renamed everything like you've mentioned. Is it possible that it has something to do with my version of js.jar or runner.js?

Comment: Updated both the js.jar and runner.js, and I still am having issues. I am at a loss now. Thank you for all the help it really is appreciated, do you know possibly anything else that might be preventing this from working?

Comment: Everything works correctly now. Thank you very much. I believe that my current dojo-1.3.2 was incomplete or tampered from the original form. Once I reacquired dojo-1.4.0-src and ran the command everything was corrected. Thank you for all the help again! Final command used (for anyone stumbling upon this same issue and is lost):

testFolder should be stored in your dojo-release-x.x.x\ directory and the command-line operation "java -jar ..\shrinksafe\js.jar runner.js testModule=testFolder.moduleName"

You may need to download the shrinksafe (or rhino) folder seperately then add it to .../util/

Comment: Great.  Glad you finally got it to work.  Still, there are at least two problems here: one, that you need to co-locate Dojo and your tests (there's an open ticket on this) and two, you can't call it "tests" (probably should open a ticket on this also)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your testFolder to be stored outside the default dojo-release-x.x.x\ directory.
Add the following to your command:
registerModulePath=tests,../myproject/tests

You may have to edit **../** properly to locate your actual directory structure.

Comment: registerModulePath is now deprecated, you should now use something like: paths=myutil,../../mydirectory/myutil

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch here: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10511 which allows running command-line tests outside of the dojo root, but it does not appear to have been applied, in dojo-1.6.1, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run DOH tests on the command line, including tests outside the dojo source tree.  Create a config file like this saying where your code modules are relative to the dojo/util/doh location:

```
require({
    paths: {
        "org/myorg" : "../../../mycode/org/myorg",
        "com/mycom" : "../../../x/com/mycom"
    }
});
```

and name it config.js.  Open a command window and cd into the directory containing the  "dijit", "dojo", "dojox" and "util" directories.  Run this command:

```
java -jar util/shrinksafe/js.jar dojo/dojo.js baseUrl=file:///full/path/to/dojo/dojo load=file://full/path/to/config.js load=doh test=com/mycom/tests
```

The full answer is here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/util/doh.html

There is a more detailed explanation here: http://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/09/running-dojo-doh-unit-tests-on-the-command-line-with-rhino/